# Temporary Password for Domain Admin

Tags: user-accounts, active-directory

A small non-profit company handling confidential information must grant remote domain admin access to their external IT services provider who manages the entire network, including new PCs, etc... Although the sensitive info is strongly encrypted, they aren't comfortable in leaving that powerful account in the hands of a third party.

Computer Associates offers a system that generates time-limited domain admin accounts on demand, with a nice log and everything. Problem is, it's extremely costly and definitely out of budget.

I offered to help the non-profit company, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this in a way that is simple enough to use for a local power user. So, what would be a simple way to generate disposable domain admin accounts? I'm not a pro but I can deal with vbscript, powershell, or VB.NET.

Thanks a lot for any pointers.

Comment: The obvious question is to verify they actually need Administrator permissions.   The simplest solution is to create a new user group which does NOT have access AT ALL to the information in question.    You can do something like [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/22/use-powershell-to-enable-or-disable-a-local-user-account.aspx) anyone asking for Administrator permissions better fully explain why they actually need it.

Comment: how is the data encrypted?

Comment: @Ramhound - makes sense... I'll have them define exactly their needs. I'm afraid they'll need a lot though, as they manage users, servers,... the whole thing!

Comment: @Keltari - they use a commercial solution independent from AD. Admins have no access.

Comment: Sounds fishy.. I wouldn't trust that answerr

Comment: @Ramhound - let's see what they say. It's a serious company, I doubt they'd try doing something stupid on purpose. The danger is more the careless employee...

Comment: @Ramhound - they just came back saying they must have a domain admin access... and I don't know where to begin with splitting the individual rights to create a user privileged enough for them to work.

Answer (score 1):

## A Domain Admin Is a Domain *Admin*

Anyone you give full Administrative permissions can do anything they want, including installing secret back-door access, falsifying audit logs, and accessing and copying off data at will. The best you can do by issuing temporary domain admin accounts is create a false sense of security for the firm.

The Domain Admin is the highest credential that can be issued in a domain. It answers to no-one and cannot be restricted by lesser or equal accounts.  Should you wish to limit it, you would need to employ a superior privilege level, something that does not exist in Active Directory.

Domain Admin credentials must only, ever, be in the hands of those you trust. If the 3rd party service provider cannot be deemed trustworthy, then they cannot have domain admin rights.  If they must have these rights to provide their services then you must first address the issue of trust among the people involved. This is not something you can do with a purely tech-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a second user and give it the only rights they need. You can set an expiration on that account, so you know they can only use it until the account expires. If you fear they edit their account, you can prevent that through a group policy or not handing out administrative access at all, or other means to restrict access to the Active Directory.

But primarily the question is, do you trust that company into helping out? Usually those companies are called in for a specific issue, for example because they support their product. And it is not in their interest to steal information, but only to help out.

Additionally, make sure someone looks at the shoulders of the IT person if you really are affraid.

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Web')^|Out-Null;1..12^|%{[Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(16,3)}
```

If you give the service the internal IT infrastructure, you have no security. This is a question of decency external service company.

The problem in the architecture of the operating system, which is not served by a separate system at the kernel level and application data separately, routes and links.

No example of such a role as "auditor", example - Novell Netware, "auditor" function is carried out only review action, but could not make any changes.

If you need security, the administrative accounts should only be you.

Accordingly, it is necessary to give an indication of problems - error messages and system applications that can be automated. And encrypted peredovat messages via SOAP, or any other way. In the opposite direction you come scripts that solve your problem, you are viewing for possible damage, having to stand and then - apply.

What you want is not security, but the game in safety. Because command line in fact - instant administration. Application - even faster. How many milliseconds you want to give administrative privileges to the other side? )))

Answer (score -1):

Here's something you could do. Give the guy access to your computers via ssh. But also, keep a script on your computer, maybe a cron job to block port 22 at a pre determined time.

Now, whenever that particular time comes, the script is executed, port 22 is blocked and even though the guy has the password, he will not be able to access the computer.

Of course, he shouldn't know where the script is, or for that matter, that the script exists at all.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? It makes perfect sense. At least, I think it does. Do leave a comment if you downvote an answer